# Unique ID within group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

```r
data <- data.table(match = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
player = c("Dave", "Dave", "Dennis", "Dave", "Jake", "Jake", "Josh", "Jake"),
 team = c("Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "England", "England", "England", "England"))
```

I want to create an ID variable that indicates the position of each player in a team for a given match. The variable, for the give dataset, would look go:

```r
ID = c(1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1)
```

I have tried using group_by and assigning row number within a group but that isn't working. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` (the function)

```
library(data.table)
data[, ID := match(player, unique(player)), match]
```

Or using `factor`

```
data[, ID := as.integer(factor(player, levels = unique(player))), match]
data
#   match player      team ID
#1:     1   Dave Australia  1
#2:     1   Dave Australia  1
#3:     1 Dennis Australia  2
#4:     1   Dave Australia  1
#5:     2   Jake   England  1
#6:     2   Jake   England  1
#7:     2   Josh   England  2
#8:     2   Jake   England  1
```

---

Similar option in `dplyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(match) %>%
   mutate(ID = match(player, unique(player)))
```